# Is there an easy way to count the elements in a recursive data structure?

Tags: c#

I have a recursive data structure in a C# object.

An object has a collection of "Parts."  Each Part also has a collection of Parts.  And so on.  The structure could theoretically nest forever.

```
object
--> Part
--> Part
  --> Part
  --> Part
    --> Part
  --> Part
--> Part
```

I want to get a count of all the Parts in this structure.  So, all the branches and leaves.  (There are 7 total Parts, in the above example.)

Is there a way to do this without initializing a counter and recursing down through the tree?  I could do this, certainly, but it seems slow and overkill-ish.  Is there a better/easier way?

Comment: Why does "initializing a counter and recursing down through the tree" sound slow?

Comment: Not that I know of, I believe you need to interrogate every Part to see if it has children, and then drill down through recursion.

Comment: Unless you recorded some counts as you created the data structure, I don't see anyway you could count everything without using recursion (or any other loop that walks through every object)

Comment: There is an iterative alternative for each recursive function, but trees are a naturally recursive structure. Embrace the recursion.

Comment: Unless you have some sort of "pre-cooked" counter, you'll need to traverse each and every element no matter whether you do it iteratively or recursively. In both cases you'll have O(N) complexity (with possibly slightly different cost per element). So I don't understand what you mean by "slow". Also this should be quite easy to implement, so what do you mean by "overkill-ish"?

Comment: For very, very deep hierarchies (think hundreds of levels), stack depth could be a problem. As long as that's not the case, recursive is the natural way to go.

Comment: As expected, there seems to be no way of counting without...counting. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A natural way of processing recursive data structures, for count or any other kind of aggregation, is employing a recursive function:

```
class Part {
    IEnumerable<Part> SubParts {get;set;}
    public int TotalParts {
        get {
            return 1 + SubParts.Sum(p => p.TotalParts);
            //     ^                       ^
            //     |                       |
            // Add one for this part       |
            //                             |
            //         Use LINQ to aggregate counts recursively
        }
    }
}
```

The function assumes that parts of lower levels are not shared among parts at the higher level, i.e. that your graph of parts is a tree. One way to improve the performance of functions like this is to cache the results at the levels below yours in the `Part`, to make sure that the recursive computation is done only once.

You could avoid recursion by implementing a queue or a stack, but the implementation wouldn't be that simple.

Comment: An iterative solution isn't *that* complex; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could override the Add method on each element and keep a count property on each Part as elements are added, similar to List.Count

Otherwise there is not going to be any more accurate way than iteration. For an estimate of size, you could take a representative sample and infer a rough size from it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-recursive solution, rather than an iterative solution, that is also able to traverse the tree and count the nodes.

```
public class Part
{
    public IEnumerable<Part> Children { get; set; }
    public int Count()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Part>();
        stack.Push(this);

        int total = 0;
        while (stack.Any())
        {
            total++;
            foreach (var child in stack.Pop().Children)
                stack.Push(child);
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I absolutely agree, iterative solution is not that hard in itself: it looks "hard" only in comparison to a recursive one-liner. In practice, however, I'd go with iterative solution only when the tree has a potential of being deep enough to pose a realistic threat of overflowing the stack.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Or if you want a breadth first search (or anything other than a depth first search).  Or if the method is `async` or an iterator block as both of those introduce a much higher "cost" to calling a method, making recursion, in general, quite a bit more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use recursion, but if you really wanted to avoid it then you could override the Add/Remove methods of the collection and use a delegate to a method on the containing object that updates a single instance of a `totalCount` variable (per containing object, not per collection). Each time a part is added or removed from any of the collections in the tree, the `totalCount` variable gets modified via the delegate.

Each collection node is oblivous to the count of it's parent/child node and the implementation of how the total count is maintained is hidden from the collections themselves.